# Why does postfix take so long time to receive emails from gmail?

Tags: networking, email, smtp, postfix, mtu

How can I manually check for an email **from the command line**? How can I force postfix to receive/update emails? The email from **gmail** takes **8 minutes** till it will be received by postfix. How can I reduce the time?

## Update:

postfix is a part of iRedMail distr on the host with public IP, no NAT is used.
Sometimes I get the email immediate, sometimes up to 30 min. Does the Postfix get the notification about email from another MTA (say gmail) to accept the email?

Comment: Please provide some details about your postfix configuration.  How are emails getting from gmail to it?

Comment: added some details. I don't really know what about config of postfix do you mean? its config file content?

Comment: You have SMTP in your tags.  Does this mean your server is configured as the MX host for a domain that you are emailing from gmail?  You are going to have to provide far more detail about how this is all working for anyone to be able to help.